# (Verilog) Why $signed() and >>> operation cannot generate ASR when inside ?: operator in such case?

Tags: verilog, quartus

Here is the module, I want to use `signext` to determine whether it is ASR or LSR.

```
module test(
    input wire [31:0] in,
    input wire [4:0] shift_amount,
    input wire signext,
    output wire [31:0] out
);
assign out = signext ? ($signed(in) >>> shift_amount) : (in >> shift_amount);
endmodule
```

However, Quartus shows `Warning (15610): No output dependent on input pin "signext"`, and RTL viewer shows it is just an LSR.

[image: RTL viewer: LSR]

Add something may fix this problem, but I cannot tell why.

**fix 1**: add `$signed()` to the ASR result:

```
assign out = signext ? $signed($signed(in) >>> shift_amount) : (in >> shift_amount);
```

**fix 2**: add `$unsigned()` to the ASR result:

```
assign out = signext ? $unsigned($signed(in) >>> shift_amount) : (in >> shift_amount);
```

**fix 3**: add `$signed()` to the LSR operand:

```
assign out = signext ? ($signed(in) >>> shift_amount) : ($signed(in) >> shift_amount);
```

**fix 4**: add `$signed()` to the LSR result:

```
assign out = signext ? ($signed(in) >>> shift_amount) : $signed(in >> shift_amount);
```

In conclusion, I guess that the **naked** result of `($signed(in) >>> shift_amount)` is forced to be `unsigned` because of the other `unsigned` value, so `>>>` means `unsigned arithmetic right shift` and is the same as LSR then.

(It's hard for a C++ programmer like me to believe that operator can be overloaded by the type of result.)

So, wrap the left side or change the type of the right side to `signed` may fix the problem.

Then I find the 5th fix.

**fix 5**: add `{}` to the ASR result:

```
assign out = signext ? {($signed(in) >>> shift_amount)} : (in >> shift_amount);
```

The problem is: **I'm not sure why this does not work and why fixes would work, I'm just guessing and trying.**

Hope someone could tell me what is really happening, thanks.

> Quartus version:
>
> Quartus II 64-Bit Version 13.1.0 Build 162 10/23/2013 SJ Full Version
>
> Also happens at:
>
> Quartus Prime Version 22.1std.1 Build 917 02/14/2023 SC Lite Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the obligatory statement: forget everything you know about programming. Verilog is not a programming language, but rather circuit design.

---

With Verilog, at the very least Quartus in particular, pretty much if any part is unsigned, be that input or output, the whole thing is unsigned. It's an annoying quirk you have to live with.

In your case because the output is to an unsigned ternary operator, it's treating the whole calculation as unsigned - essentially **casting any signed operands to unsigned** before performing the operation.

All of you 'fixes' split the shift operation out from the ternary operator and allow the sub operation output (from the shift) to be treated as signed, thus the cast to unsigned in the ternary operator no longer affects the shift.

Equally you could use the much clearer and descriptive:

```
signed wire [31:0] signedShift;
wire [31:0] unsignedShift;

assign signedShift = $signed(in) >>> shift_amount;
assign unsignedShift = in >> shift_amount;
assign out = signext ? signedShift : unsignedShift;
```

Remember that in Verilog, fewer lines is not more efficient, its just less descriptive.

Comment: Tom is correct.  See [Sutherland gotchas around slide 14](https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-SNUG-Boston_standard_gotchas_presentation.pdf) or section IEEE 1364 2005 section 5.4.1